# Using date commands in calculated fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula, regional-settings

I am following this article:
[Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

A simple sample is this:

```
=DATEDIF([Dato1],[Dato2],"d")
```

However when I save the column I get following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

If I just do this it works:

```
=[Dato1]-[Dato2]
```

However I need to calculate hours and days between two dates so I need some of the commands.

Any pointer what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Non-US regional settings? Use semi-colon instead of colon. (;)

Comment: Colon.. who am I. I meant comma of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Try using this:

```
=DATEDIF([Dato1];[Dato2];"d")
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks.

Comment: Thank for for the answer.