# Multiple IFs and ORs

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, if-condition

I'm new to SharePoint lists and prefer not to work with them, but my employer has decided to utilize it. The process/formula I have in excel works, but not in SharePoint lists.

We need a Calculated column that shows "Incomplete" if one or more of the cells are empty

The formula I have is:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(E2),ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(G2),ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(I2),ISBLANK(J2)),"Incomplete","Complete")
```

I know for SharePoint, I use the column names.

The question I have in how on earth do I translate this to SharePoint language.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Create a calculated column, and replace B2/C2 etc with actual column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this which is based on your inputs.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2), OR(ISBLANK(C2), OR(ISBLANK(D2), OR(ISBLANK(E2), OR(ISBLANK(F2), OR(ISBLANK(G2), OR(ISBLANK(H2), OR(ISBLANK(I2), ISBLANK(J2))))))))), "Incomplete", "Complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

For you requirements, you need to create a Calculate column in list.

Follow below articles for creating calculate column in SharePoint list:

1. [Calculate data in lists or libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-data-in-lists-or-libraries-c5261743-667f-4833-bede-e516cef2a0e1)
2. [How to create a Calculated Column in a SharePoint list or library](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-calculated-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/)

---

Syntax for the formula in SharePoint is similar to what you are using in Excel currently.

Also, you are correct that instead of B2, C2, D2 etc., you have to use the display names of SharePoint list columns.

The current formula you added to your question should work on SharePoint as it is.

Few points to remember:

1. If there are spaces in display name of column, surround it by `[]` in formula, like:

   ```
   =IF(OR(ISBLANK([Column 1]), ISBLANK([Column 1]), ISBLANK([Column 1]), ISBLANK(E2), ISBLANK(F2), ISBLANK(G2), ISBLANK(H2), ISBLANK(I2), ISBLANK(J2)), "Incomplete", "Complete")
   ```
2. If your formula is throwing syntax error even if everything in formula is correct, try using semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

   **Source**: [Using date commands in calculated fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292917/using-date-commands-in-calculated-fields/292919#292919)

---

Also, check below Microsoft official documentations for calculated column formulas:

1. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)
2. [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)
3. [OR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)
4. [IS functions - ISBLANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)